# What is the required recursive function(s) in Scheme programming language to compute the following series?

Tags: recursion, scheme

what is the required recursive function(s) in Scheme programming language to compute the following series?? Explanation needed

> 1^2/2^1 + 3^4/4^3 + 5^6/6^5 + 7^8/8^7 + 9^10/10^9
>
> [image: x]

Answer (score 1):

So, well, what does each term look like?  It's n^(n+1)/(n+1)^n.  And you want to stop when you reach 10 (so if n > 10, stop).  So write a function of a single argument, n,  which either:

- returns 0 if n > 10;
- adds n^(n+1)/(n+1)^n to the result of calling itself on n + 2.

Then this function with argument 1 will compute what you want.  Going backwards may be easier:

- return 0 if n < 1;
- add n^(n+1)/(n+1)^n to the result of calling itself on n - 2;

then the function with argument 10 is what you want.

---

Or you could do this which is more entertaining:

```
(define s
  (λ (l)
    ((λ (c i a)
       (if (> i l)
           a
           (c c
              (+ i 2)
              (+ a (/ (expt i (+ i 1))
                      (expt (+ i 1) i))))))
     (λ (c i a)
       (if (> i l)
           a
           (c c
              (+ i 2)
              (+ a (/ (expt i (+ i 1))
                      (expt (+ i 1) i))))))
     1 0)))
```

But I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//power function
(define (power a b)
     (if (zero? b) //base case
      1    
     (* a (power a (- b 1))))) //or return power of a,b

// sum function for series

    (define (sum n)
     (if (< n 3) //base case 
         0.5
       (+ (/  (power (- n 1) n) (power n (- n 1))) (sum (- n 2 ))  ))) //recursion call

>(sum 10) // call sum function here .
```